# Index exceeds matrix dimensions - Partial Fractions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
syms s

x = input(' please enter value for x ');

w = input(' please enter value for w ');

i1=(2*x);

i2=( (x*x) + (w*w) );

b=[1 -1];

a=[1 i1 i2];

[r,p,k]= residue(b,a)

PFE= ( ( r(1)/( (k(1)*s) - (p(1)) ) ) ) + ( r(1)/( (k(1)*s) - (p(1)) ) );

disp(PFE)

ilaplace(PFE)
```

I am getting the Index exceeds matrix dimensions error when I run this. I don't know how to fix it? I've googled this but all of the previous examples have loops and mine don't. I'm stumped, can someone please help?

Comment: Does the error say which line? That will help narrow it down to the function that's having the issue.

Comment: have you verified that `r`, `p` and `k` are not empty? If they are, that would explain the error as you are trying to access their 1st element.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it. LOL after a few minutes of putting this question out. This is what I got

```
syms s
x = input(' please enter value for x ');
w = input(' please enter value for w ');
i1=(2*x);
i2=( (x*x) + (w*w) );
b=[1 -1];
a=[1 i1 i2];
[r,p,k]= residue(b,a)
PFE=  ( (r(1))/(s-p(1))) + ( (r(2))/(s-p(2) )) ;
disp(PFE)
ilaplace(PFE)
```

I fixed it by changing the PFE equation.